# noip install on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, make

I'm trying to install [noip](https://www.noip.com)
on Ubuntu 12.04.4, and I do not know the first thing about building/compiling software.

The README file stated these exact words:

> HOW TO BUILD AN EXECUTABLE FOR YOUR SYSTEM
>
> The command 
>       make 
>   will build a binary of the noip2 client that will run on your system.
>
> If you do not have 'make' installed and you have an i686 Linux machine 
>   with libc6, a binary for i686 systems is located in the binaries 
>   directory called noip2-Linux. Copy that binary to the build directory 
>     'cp binaries/noip2-Linux noip2'
>
> The command
>       make install
>   (which must be run as root) will install the various pieces to their
>   appropriate places.  This will ask questions and build a configuration 
>   data file.
>   See below if you can't become root or can't write in /usr/local/*.

evidently they want me to use make, however when I try [operating under root]:

```
anon@anon:~$ make -f /home/noip-2.1.9-1/makefile
```

I get the following:

```
make: /home/noip-2.1.9-1/makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/noip-2.1.9-1/makefile'.  Stop.
anon@anon:~$
```

SO! What am I doing wrong, and is there a simpler way?

If you found the answers helpful, please upvote the answers as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a clean Ubuntu 12.04, I followed their instructions found here: [How to Install the Linux Dynamic Update Client on Ubuntu](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/) and successfully installed their client. I added a couple of commands to install missing/required components....

```
$sudo su -
#cd /usr/local/src
#apt-get install wget
#wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
#apt-get install make 
#apt-get install gcc
#tar -xf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
#cd noip-2.1.9-1/
#make install
if [ ! -d /usr/local/bin ]; then mkdir -p /usr/local/bin;fi
if [ ! -d /usr/local/etc ]; then mkdir -p /usr/local/etc;fi
cp noip2 /usr/local/bin/noip2
/usr/local/bin/noip2 -C -c /tmp/no-ip2.conf

Auto configuration for Linux client of no-ip.com.

Please enter the login/email string for no-ip.com  ############
Please enter the password for user '###########'  ****************

Only one host [##########.no-ip.biz] is registered to this account.
It will be used.
Please enter an update interval:[30]  
Do you wish to run something at successful update?[N] (y/N)  

New configuration file '/tmp/no-ip2.conf' created.

mv /tmp/no-ip2.conf /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf
```

That was it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not configured the makefile. You can achieve this by running configure before you make. There is also a much easier way using APT(advanced package tool) to download and install. APT is fairly easy to use and you can chech if the package is available via apt-cache search noip. If there is a package available you can run apt-get install noip. [Manual Install](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-tutorials-howtos-reference-material/64958-how-install-software-linux.html) ..... [APT install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto). Hope this helps